# copying c char pointer to a non pointer char

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Is there any problem on doing that?

```
char* field = new char[2];
field[0] = 'S';
field[1] = '\0';

char c = *field;
```

will c always be equal to 'S'?

Answer (score 4):

No problem with that, c will always be 'S'.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally fine - and c will always be equal to 'S'.  Dereferencing `field`, a pointer of type `char` will result in a `char`.

Comment: Actually, dereferencing a pointer of type `char` yields a `char&`

Comment: @ildjarn: Nope, it doesn't. It yields `char` lvalue, take a look at §5.3.1/1 (well, at least in n3291).

Comment: @Vitus : And how can a "function" return an lvalue in C++ other than by reference? (I realize no function is invoked here, but *semantically*...)

Comment: @ildjarn: Well, it behaves _as if_ it returned a `char&`, but you can't just say it returns a reference - that's how the standard is written. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in that `new char[2]` is not C syntax. The general idea is correct, though: `c` will always be 'S'.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that. When you dereference the field array in the line

```
char c = *field;
```

what you're actually asking is for the value of the first element of the array, in this case 'S'.